# Z-indexing/Display Issue

Tags: html, css, z-index

I've been wracking my brain trying to figure out this issue, and I can't seem to figure out how to get my menu to display over the underlying elements.
I've had this issue before, but I've always been able to remedy it by fixing the z-indexing.
I can't seem to manage it this time -- any thoughts guys?

Here's an example of the site(not complete, just working on this issue right now) where the issue is happening, you should be able to play with it a bit with google dev tools or something a-kin :).

http://202388.yourwebsite.cc/

Comment: It's helpful to post the important code here. Links can change in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The menu isn't appearing because of the `overflow:hidden` portion of `.container`. If you remove that it should work just fine.